# phone number authentication with firebase and facing problem

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

> `E/FirebaseAuth : [SmsRetriverHelper] Sms verification code failed: unknown status code : 1*0*5 null`

OTP is not sent on mobile number.

After clicking `send Otp` it opens browser and asking for a captcha after this window activity I got this problem.

`login.kt`:

```
package com.example.egc5

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.Toast

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseTooManyRequestsException
import com.google.firebase.auth.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class log_in : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var sendOTPBtn : Button
    private lateinit var phoneNumberET : EditText
    private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var number : String
    private lateinit var mProgressBar : ProgressBar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in)

        init()
        sendOTPBtn.setOnClickListener {
            number = phoneNumberET.text.trim().toString()
            if (number.isNotEmpty()){
                if (number.length == 10){
                    number = "+91$number"
                    mProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
                        .setPhoneNumber(number)       // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(callbacks) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .build()
                    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this , "Please Enter correct Number" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this , "Please Enter Number" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar!!.hide()
        }
    }

    private fun init(){
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.phoneProgressBar)
        mProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        sendOTPBtn = findViewById(R.id.sendOTPBtn)
        phoneNumberET = findViewById(R.id.phoneEditTextNumber)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }

    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Toast.makeText(this , "Authenticate Successfully" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    sendToMain()
                } else {
                    // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                    Log.d("TAG", "signInWithPhoneAuthCredential: ${task.exception.toString()}")
                    if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        Toast.makeText(this , "TRY AGAIN" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                        // The verification code entered was invalid
                    }
                    // Update UI
                }
                mProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
    }

    private fun sendToMain(){
        startActivity(Intent(this , MainActivity2::class.java))
    }
    private val callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
            // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
            // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
            //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
            // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
            //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
            //     user action.
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.

            if (e is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                Log.d("TAG", "onVerificationFailed: ${e.toString()}")
            } else if (e is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                Log.d("TAG", "onVerificationFailed: ${e.toString()}")
            }
            mProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            // Show a message and update the UI
        }

        override fun onCodeSent(
            verificationId: String,
            token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
        ) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.
            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            val intent = Intent(this@log_in , otp::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("OTP" , verificationId)
            intent.putExtra("resendToken" , token)
            intent.putExtra("phoneNumber" , number)
            startActivity(intent)
            mProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }

    }



    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if (auth.currentUser != null){
            startActivity(Intent(this , MainActivity2::class.java))
        }    }
}
```

"***otp.kt***

```
package com.example.egc5
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseTooManyRequestsException
import com.google.firebase.auth.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

class otp : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var verifyBtn: Button
    private lateinit var resendTV: TextView
    private lateinit var inputOTP1: EditText
    private lateinit var inputOTP2: EditText
    private lateinit var inputOTP3: EditText
    private lateinit var inputOTP4: EditText
    private lateinit var inputOTP5: EditText
    private lateinit var inputOTP6: EditText
    private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar

    private lateinit var OTP: String
    private lateinit var resendToken: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
    private lateinit var phoneNumber: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp)

        OTP = intent.getStringExtra("OTP").toString()
        resendToken = intent.getParcelableExtra("resendToken")!!
        phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("phoneNumber")!!

        init()
        progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        addTextChangeListener()
        resendOTPTvVisibility()

        resendTV.setOnClickListener {
            resendVerificationCode()
            resendOTPTvVisibility()
        }
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar!!.hide()
        }

        verifyBtn.setOnClickListener {
            //collect otp from all the edit texts
            val typedOTP =
                (inputOTP1.text.toString() + inputOTP2.text.toString() + inputOTP3.text.toString()
                        + inputOTP4.text.toString() + inputOTP5.text.toString() + inputOTP6.text.toString())

            if (typedOTP.isNotEmpty()) {
                if (typedOTP.length == 6) {
                    val credential: PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                        OTP, typedOTP
                    )
                    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Correct OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter OTP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }


        }
    }

    private fun resendOTPTvVisibility() {
        inputOTP1.setText("")
        inputOTP2.setText("")
        inputOTP3.setText("")
        inputOTP4.setText("")
        inputOTP5.setText("")
        inputOTP6.setText("")
        resendTV.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        resendTV.isEnabled = false

        Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!).postDelayed({
            resendTV.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            resendTV.isEnabled = true
        }, 60000)
    }

    private fun resendVerificationCode() {
        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
            .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
            .setCallbacks(callbacks)
            .setForceResendingToken(resendToken)// OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
    }

    private val callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
            // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
            // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
            //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
            // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
            //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
            //     user action.
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
        }

        override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.

            if (e is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                // Invalid request
                Log.d("TAG", "onVerificationFailed: ${e.toString()}")
            } else if (e is FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                Log.d("TAG", "onVerificationFailed: ${e.toString()}")
            }
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            // Show a message and update the UI
        }

        override fun onCodeSent(
            verificationId: String,
            token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken
        ) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.
            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            OTP = verificationId
            resendToken = token
        }
    }

    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Authenticate Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    sendToMain()
                } else {
                    // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                    Log.d("TAG", "signInWithPhoneAuthCredential: ${task.exception.toString()}")
                    if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        // The verification code entered was invalid
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }
                    // Update UI
                }
                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
    }

    private fun sendToMain() {
        startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
    }

    private fun addTextChangeListener() {
        inputOTP1.addTextChangedListener(EditTextWatcher(inputOTP1))
        inputOTP2.addTextChangedListener(EditTextWatcher(inputOTP2))
        inputOTP3.addTextChangedListener(EditTextWatcher(inputOTP3))
        inputOTP4.addTextChangedListener(EditTextWatcher(inputOTP4))
        inputOTP5.addTextChangedListener(EditTextWatcher(inputOTP5))
        inputOTP6.addTextChangedListener(EditTextWatcher(inputOTP6))
    }

    private fun init() {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.otpProgressBar)
        verifyBtn = findViewById(R.id.verifyOTPBtn)
        resendTV = findViewById(R.id.resendTextView)
        inputOTP1 = findViewById(R.id.otpEditText1)
        inputOTP2 = findViewById(R.id.otpEditText2)
        inputOTP3 = findViewById(R.id.otpEditText3)
        inputOTP4 = findViewById(R.id.otpEditText4)
        inputOTP5 = findViewById(R.id.otpEditText5)
        inputOTP6 = findViewById(R.id.otpEditText6)
    }


    inner class EditTextWatcher(private val view: View) : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

            val text = p0.toString()
            when (view.id) {
                R.id.otpEditText1 -> if (text.length == 1) inputOTP2.requestFocus()
                R.id.otpEditText2 -> if (text.length == 1) inputOTP3.requestFocus() else if (text.isEmpty()) inputOTP1.requestFocus()
                R.id.otpEditText3 -> if (text.length == 1) inputOTP4.requestFocus() else if (text.isEmpty()) inputOTP2.requestFocus()
                R.id.otpEditText4 -> if (text.length == 1) inputOTP5.requestFocus() else if (text.isEmpty()) inputOTP3.requestFocus()
                R.id.otpEditText5 -> if (text.length == 1) inputOTP6.requestFocus() else if (text.isEmpty()) inputOTP4.requestFocus()
                R.id.otpEditText6 -> if (text.isEmpty()) inputOTP5.requestFocus()

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Besides that, if you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400** (four hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).